# Improving performance of a OData REST API call on a large document library

Tags: 2013, rest, odata

I have a requirement that requires that we use a built URL leveraging the REST API for our SharePoint 2013 site on a document library with many (about 800,000) documents.  The format of the URL is roughly as follows:

`https://server/_api/lists/getbytitle('listtitle')/items$filter=...&$select=...`

The filter has multiple filters, and it returns more than one field.

The performance of the query is horrible.  I feel like it pulls every document before applying the filters and projections.  Is there any best practices to improve performance of the RESTful call?

Comment: Are you locked into using a single URL?  Can you switch to making and ajax call so you can change the headers and access the JSON light REST interface?

Comment: I'm locked into using a URL, but not into using a single RESTful call.